# How to create two user records and then verify user count is 2 in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I want to see how many admins there are when I add 2 so I do

```
describe "how many admins" do

  let!(:user1) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, username: 'user1', password: 'abc123', admin: true) }
  let!(:user2) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, username: 'user2', password: 'abc123', admin: true) }

  its "how many" do
    expect(User.where(admin: true).count).to eq 2
  end

end
```

but I'm getting

```
  1) how many admins how many should eq 2
     Failure/Error: expect(User.where(admin: true).count).to eq 2

       expected: 2
            got: 0

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.84695 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:
```

Why not 2?

My user class is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
require 'digest/sha1'
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :admin

  validates_presence_of     :username
  validates_uniqueness_of   :username
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validate :password_non_blank

  def self.delete_me(user)
    how_many_admins = User.where(admin: true).count
    if how_many_admins > 1 
      puts "delete ok!"
      user.delete
    else
      puts "delete not ok!"
    end 
  end 

  def self.authenticate(name, password)
    user = self.find_by_username(name)
    if user
      expected_password = encrypted_password(password, user.salt)
      if user.pwd_hashed != expected_password
        user = nil 
      end 
    end 
    user
  end 
  def password
    @password
  end 

  def password=(pwd)
    @password = pwd 
    return if pwd.blank?
    create_new_salt
    self.pwd_hashed = User.encrypted_password(self.password, self.salt)
  end 

  def is_admin
    admin ? 'Yes' : 'No'
  end 

private
  def password_non_blank
    errors.add(:password, "Missing password") if pwd_hashed.blank?
  end 

  def create_new_salt
    self.salt = self.object_id.to_s + rand.to_s
  end 

  def self.encrypted_password(password, salt)
    string_to_hash = password + "wibble" + salt
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(string_to_hash)
  end 

end
```

I'm using FactoryGirl right now -

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    username "Michael Durrant"
  end 

  factory :admin, parent: :group do
    username "Admin Durrant"
  end 

end
```

but I get the same result just using build or create

Seems to work ok in the console as long as I use a unique name which should be the case in the test anyway for the test database.  For dev I have to use a new one, and when I do I get:

```
2.0.0-p247 :011 > FactoryGirl.create(:user, username: 'user40', password: 'abc123', admin: true)
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = BINARY 'user40' LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`admin`, `created_at`, `pwd_hashed`, `salt`, `updated_at`, `username`) VALUES (NULL, '2014-08-02 00:57:16', 'fc05df3b09984e6757d4244bce99c2efb0bc13a3', '322168600.420475518581534', '2014-08-02 00:57:16', 'user40')
   (45.0ms)  COMMIT
 => #<User id: 17, username: "user40", pwd_hashed: "fc05df3b09984e6757d4244bce99c2efb0bc13a3", salt: "322168600.420475518581534", created_at: "2014-08-02 00:57:16", updated_at: "2014-08-02 00:57:16", admin: nil> 
2.0.0-p247 :012 >
```

I've verified my test database itself is empty between runs with:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test rails c
User.all
Loading test environment (Rails 3.2.17)
2.0.0-p247 :001 > User.all
  User Load (5.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` 
 => [] 
2.0.0-p247 :002 >
```

Similarly, without FactoryGirl:

```
describe "how many admins" do

  let!(:user1) { User.create(username: 'user100', password: 'abc123', admin: true) }
  let!(:user2) { User.create(username: 'user200', password: 'abc123', admin: true) }
  #let!(:user1) { FactoryGirl.create(:user_admin, username: 'user100', password: 'abc123') }
  #let!(:user2) { FactoryGirl.create(:user_admin, username: 'user200', password: 'abc123') }

  its "how many" do
    expect(User.where(admin: true).count).to eq 2
  end

end
```

gives

```
Failures:

1) how many admins how many should eq 2
   Failure/Error: expect(User.where(admin: true).count).to eq 2

     expected: 2
          got: 0
```

Comment: I think you should also set `password_confirmation` when you create your user

Comment: Try running `FactoryGirl.create(:user, username: 'user1', password: 'abc123', admin: true)` in the console and see if it properly creates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `attr_accessor :admin` which overrides the setters and getters for the `admin` column.  You also need to make sure that the factory contains the minimum requirement in order for you to create a record.  This means that you have to use sequencing for `username` and add `password` and `password_confirmation` to your factory.

The final thing you need to do is to remove the `attr_accessor :admin` line and your tests should pass.

Comment: Yes this was the problem.  removing that fixed the test.

Answer (score 0):

You have the validation for password confirmation, so your spec should be

```
describe "how many admins" do

  let!(:user1) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, username: 'user1', password: 'abc123', password_confirmation: 'abc123', admin: true) }
  let!(:user2) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, username: 'user2', password: 'abc123', password_confirmation: 'abc123', admin: true) }

  its "how many" do
    expect(User.where(admin: true).count).to eq 2
  end

end
```

Comment: This did not resolve the issues.  btw I can't can create a record without that field as seen in `FactoryGirl.create(:user, username: 'user40', password: 'abc123', admin: true)` which worked